# Passing data from modal to component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I have a users list with the pagination. I'm using ngbModal for a popup. On close modal how can I send pages data from the edit user modal to the user component?

**Dialog service**

```
    openDialog(props: any, component:any): Promise<any> {
    debugger
    console.log(props)
    var modelRef = this.ngbModel.open(component, { size: 'md  ', backdrop: 'static' });
    modelRef.componentInstance.props = props;
    return modelRef.result;
  }
```

**User component.ts**

```
 opendialog(data: any) {
    this.dialogService
      .openDialog(
        {
          title: 'Edit User',
          page:`page=${this.page}&size=${this.pageSize}`
          type: 'edit',
        },
        EditComponent
      )
      .then((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

**edit modal.ts**

```
  setDialogProps(dialogdata: any) {
        this.pages= dialogdata.page; 
      }
      editUser(){
        this.userService.edit(this.form.value,id).subscribe((res:any)=>{
this.ngbActivemodal.close(this.pages)
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MatDialogRef has `afterClosed` observable which you can use to get the data.

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mndxlpaleda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts) is the example from official material docs.